# Uploading profile pictures to users separate folder

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to know how can i place the pictures/files(pdf's,ppt's,doc's) into the users respective folder. Like if he/she uploads her avatar and i want it to upload to path:- www.oursite.com/uploads/profile_pics/**username**/filename.jpg.

My question is that how can i create that **username** directory. Below is the code snippet:-

```
if (isset($_FILES['pic']['name']))
{
  $_FILES['pic']['name'] = $pic_uniq_id;//already set using uniqid()
  $img_title = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
  $target_dest = "uploads/#profile_faces/HERE USERNAME FOLDER/".$img_title;
  $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $target_dest);
  if(!$move) {
    $img_msg = "<p class='pic_warning' color='red'><font color='red'><b>
    Sorry! Upload failed. Try again</b></font></p>";
    include 'includes/uploadprofilepicture.inc';
     exit();
  }else {//go on...}
```

How can i create that directory with username's name?

Comment: In php you can make directories with the function `mkdir` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php Basically `mkdir("uploads/#profile_faces/" . $username)` before moving the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the user name directory using,

```
mkdir("uploads/#profile_faces/".$username);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
$user = "Username";
$path = "uploads/#profile_faces/".$user;
mkdir($path);
$target_dest = $path."/".$img_title;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get username from sessions. So if you save usernames in session variable like `$_SESSION['username']` your code would be like:

And when you create a directory you have to make sure that you have write access to it.

```
if (isset($_FILES['pic']['name'])) {

      if (!file_exists("uploads/#profile_faces/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/")) {
        mkdir("uploads/#profile_faces/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/", 0777, true);
      }

      $_FILES['pic']['name'] = $pic_uniq_id;//already set using uniqid()
      $img_title = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
      $target_dest = "uploads/#profile_faces/" . $_SESSION['username'] . "/".$img_title;
      $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $target_dest);

      if(!$move) {
        $img_msg = "<p class='pic_warning' color='red'><font color='red'><b>
        Sorry! Upload failed. Try again</b></font></p>";
        include 'includes/uploadprofilepicture.inc';
         exit();
      }

} else {
    //go on...
}
```